# Can multiple oracle jdbc cursors be parsed in parallel?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, cursor

My Procedure returns several cursors. Can they be parsed in parallel using separate java threads ? They share same connection. Would read from multiple cursors be efficient ?

Comment: Oracle procedure

Answer (score 0):

Using the Oracle Database JDBC drivers, no. Only one Java thread can access a Connection at a time. This includes any child object of the Connection such as a Statement, ResultSet, Blob, Struct, etc. The Oracle Database JDBC dev team strongly discourages allowing more than one Java thread to even reference a Connection or its child objects.

If you reuse a Connection via a Connection pool there is no problem with having one thread use the Connection, return it to the pool, then having a different thread check out the Connection and use it.